# Heroku app seems to be pulling from wrong Git respository/branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github

My problem seems to be due to my lack of understanding with how Git and Heroku communicate, but here it is:

I have/had two Heroku apps running fine for the same project - one staging and one production.  Originally, I had both apps connected to the same `master branch` in my Git repository.  I'd just push all staging changes up to the staging app with `git push heroku-staging master`, and when I wanted to push up to the production app, I'd just run `git push heroku master`.

For clarity, these are my remotes. I replaced my app with `my-app`:

```
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/my-app.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/my-app.git (push)
heroku-staging  git@heroku.com:my-app-staging.git (fetch)
heroku-staging  git@heroku.com:my-app-staging.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:My-app/my-app.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:My-app/my-app.git (push)
```

And here are my branches:

```
dev           cbafa55 added new badge
master        cb5f4c4 split seeds into different services
* staging       cbafa55 added new badge
```

Recently, I realized I should keep all my staging changes in a separate staging branch on my repository, and keep my production environment at one spot in the master branch.

So I'm now using a staging branch in the repository (which already existed but wasn't being used) for everything I want to throw up to the staging app, and the master branch will be used for the production app.

I had some trouble getting the staging branch to match what I have locally, so I just used `git reset --hard (commit_id)`, where the commit_id was the last commit I made that I was satisfied with.  So at this point, my staging branch in the git repo matches perfectly with where I want it, and I confirmed on github, to make sure everything on the staging branch is the same.

But when I push up to heroku-staging now, it seems to still be pulling from the master branch.  Even though I'm currently in my staging branch, and pushing from there.  I added everything, and committed everything, but when I push it up, it tells me everything is up to date, and on my staging app, I see a fairly old familiar error in the logs (just something I remember screwing up in the application itself).  When I look at my staging branch, though, it doesn't have the code that produces that error.  However, my master branch does still have the code that produces that error (since I haven't pushed to the master branch in a while).

I've tried using `git push heroku-staging staging`, and `git push heroku-staging master`, both from my local staging branch (which has all my current changes), both of which yield a message that says everything is up to date.  I'm not sure exactly how heroku apps make the connection to branches, but these are the only two options I can think of.

I also looked at the activity of my app on the heroku dashboard, and it says the most recent build was successful, and deployed `cb5f4c4`, which is the most recent commit from my master branch (which I don't want).  This makes sense, my heroku-staging app is producing that error that exists on the master branch, but I'm not sure why it's using this commit.

Apologies for the novel of a question, but just wanted to be thorough with the things I've done/tried.

I've hit a wall, and can't think of any more ideas.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need this:

```
git push heroku-staging staging:master
```

which will push all the changes from your local `staging` branch into your remote `master` of `heroku-staging`.

See this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971550/how-to-push-different-local-git-branches-to-heroku-master) for more information about how to push different local git branches to heroku.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I remember trying `git push heroku-staging origin:staging` as well.  I guess I missed this buried somewhere in the heroku docs.

Comment: You are most welcome. I also learned this recently as I had to do the same thing :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to push the changes in your `staging` branch to your Heroku staging site configured as git remote `heroku-staging` you need to do:

```
git push heroku-staging staging:master
```

Heroku will only deploy the master branch so you need to push your local `staging` branch to the remote `master`. It looks a little weird but this is just the git command for pushing a local branch into a different remote branch.

Comment: I'd try to do [`git push -uf heroku-staging staging:master`](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=git+push+-fu+heroku-staging+staging%3Amaster). `-f` because you may need to overwrite the existing branch, and `-u` to keep the traking between the local `staging` to the remote `master`.

Comment: @w0lf use -f only if you really need to and understand that it rewrites history. Normally you shouldn't need it unless you or somebody else has rebased or amended a commit that had already been pushed.

Comment: Right. I was thinking that the remote `master` could have extra commits compared to the local `staging` branch, which would have required the `-f`. On a second thought, though, staging features should be ahead of master, so a simple push would work fine. I'd still try the `-u` though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Worked.