# Heroku does not upgrade python version

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy a django project in Heroku but the package `django-mongoengine` needs a python version >=3.7.
I have declare the `runtime.txt` file with one of the aviable python versions for Heroku but when I deploy the project, python-3.6.12 is still being installed.

```
Total 4 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.12
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting Django==3.0.5
remote:          Downloading Django-3.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (7.5 MB)
remote:        Collecting django-mongoengine==0.4.4
remote:          Downloading django-mongoengine-0.4.4.tar.gz (186 kB)
remote:          Installing build dependencies: started
remote:          Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Getting requirements to build wheel: started
remote:          Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
remote:            Preparing wheel metadata: started
remote:            Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
remote:        ERROR: Package 'django-mongoengine' requires a different Python: 3.6.12 not in '>=3.7'
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

The content of my runtime file is:

```
python-3.7.9
```

And my Procfile file is:

```
web: gunicorn graffitisWeb.wsgi
```

Also the structure of the project is:

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        02/12/2020     10:13                ayuntamientoApp
d-----        22/01/2021     17:25                clienteApp
d-----        02/12/2020     10:13                Ejemplos bd
d-----        21/01/2021      9:55                graffitiApp
d-----        21/01/2021      9:56                graffitisWeb
-a----        21/01/2021      9:55            314 .gitignore
-a----        23/11/2020     13:05            653 manage.py
-a----        21/01/2021     11:24             31 Procfile
-a----        21/01/2021      9:55           4490 README.md
-a----        22/01/2021     18:04           2412 requirements.txt
-a----        22/01/2021     18:11             12 runtime.txt
```

Is there anything wrong that I am doing? Or is this a problem of Heroku?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the encoding of your `runtime.txt` file?

Comment: I am using vs code, so the enconding is UTF-8.

Comment: Your editor is irrelevant; VSCode is capable of writing files in other encodings. Are you sure it's UTF-8?

Comment: Yeah I know, I am just saying that my editor is configure to use UTF-8 with CRLF end of line.

Comment: Got it. Okay, thanks. You're sure this file is committed, and that the commit you are deploying to Heroku includes this file?

Comment: I am saving my project on github and the `runtime.txt` is there so I think it is committed when I push to heroku.

Comment: Alright. Are you able to share the repository link?

Comment: Of course, [here](https://github.com/juliarobles/graffitisWeb/tree/heroku) it is.

Comment: Are you deploying via [GitHub integration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration) or via `git push`? Which branch are you deploying? Your `master` branch does _not_ contain a `runtime.txt`, and I suspect that's the one that's being built.

Comment: I am deploying using `git push heroku master` from my computer at the branch `heroku`. I am not very used to work with git and it's possible that I am not using the correct command.

Comment: That's the problem. To deploy a specific branch you need to provide it on the command line, e.g. `git push heroku heroku:master` to deploy your local `heroku` branch.

Comment: That solves the problem. Thank you so much! I needed to get this to work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to push different local Git branches to Heroku/master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971550/how-to-push-different-local-git-branches-to-heroku-master)

Comment: Yes, it is very helpful.